# people stealing my money from my bank account

Tags: anonymity

Hay guys I was just wondering how am I supposed to do about someone stealing my money out of my bank account 
I've blocked the card and closed down the account.. But still he get money from me!?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Tor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your bank. Ask to speak with the fraud office. They can open an investigation on what is happening.